# Which should I use? Stepper or DC motor?

Tags: dc-motor, stepper-motor, stepper-driver

I have a project where I have to sweep a windshield wiper about 90° at a rate of 150 sweeps/minute. (~3 sweeps/second)

Since the sweep rate is high, I was thinking of using a stepper motor to get it done.

I will get the specs of the wiper soon after which I may be able to estimate the voltage,current and torque requirements.

But I need advice regarding the motor and driver choice since the project timeline is short and we cannot afford to make mistakes.

Edit: I'm a bit inclined towards a stepper motor due to it's speed and sweep controllability, though will it be able to accelerate and decelerate the load at such a high rate?

Edit: I realise that the windshield link mechanism to convert rotational motion into sweeping one would be a much better approach and a brushed DC motor would do the job nicely. So the only challenge remaining is getting enough torque and rpm out of it.

P.s I checked some wiper motors, they have 55 rpm with 40 kg-cm torque

Comment: Stepper is an option. Back of the envelope: 120 degrees sweep = 240 degree round trip. 3x / second => 720 degrees/second motion.  => 400steps/sec with standard 1.8deg stepper. Not much room in steps/second for gear reduction, maybe factor of 2-2.5, so it will be a question of torque vs motor size...

Comment: IMO: DC motor. Steppers are for precision control which you don't need. BTW I believe car windshield wipers actually drive the motor in one direction and use a mechanical mechanism to make the wiper go back and forth.

Comment: I saw the mechanism, you are correct

Comment: Have you investigated the potential use of windshield wiper motors?  Either ones designed for an airplane or a car?  I met an aircraft mechanic once.  To replace a small metal plate he had to make a plan, citing relevant procedures and rules, sign out exactly the materials required, affect the repair according to procedure, and then complete documentation.  He could spend several hours on a plate, a few tubes of goo and a dozen "cherry rivets".  After talking to him, it seems like you might be at risk of half-assing the design of an aircraft.

Comment: @KH it's for a movie shoot

Comment: Lol good answer.  You still might want to check out automotive wiper motors.  If nothing else, they run at a convenient voltage and have relatively standardized control.  The control unit for one is apparently called a wiper pulse module.

Comment: @KH they tried automotive wiper previously, it was very slow, couldn't achieve the 150 sweeps a min rate

Comment: The stepper motor brings extra complication and probably expense.  The advantage I see for set design would be that once you learn how to use it, you could repurpose it for a wide array of effects.

Comment: I would suggest that may mean your 150 sweeps/min figure is too high, but if you're stuck with that number you might need to choose a significantly oversized motor and do an investigation of what control methods would be adequate to determine if you really need a stepper.

Comment: @user253751 aptly suggested the mechanism to convert the rotation to a swipe motion... I realise this is a much better approach

Comment: @nalostta In fact, why not grab a whole windscreen wiper assembly from a car at a junkyard?

Comment: @user253751 it's not fitting the fuselage, plus the two wipers are to be controlled independently so 2 links and motors are to be used

Answer (score 1):

3 sweeps per second means that you are going to be spending a large part of the time accelerating the wiper. You need to build this into your torque calculation and it will lead to a requirement for very high starting torque.

A series wound DC motor will probably be most suitable for this.

You have not told us where your requirement has come from, perhaps a rotating glass clear view screen would be more suitable.

Comment: We are trying to implement the windshield wiper of an airplane. I'm inclined towards a stepper motor because of the speed and the angle control. Otherwise I'd have add in extra measures to check the sweep angle as well

Comment: Just out of curiosity, they actually do *small* series wound motors? Up to about 0.5kW I only see permanent magnet ones. Or are you maybe talking about universal appliance motors?

Answer (score 0):

'Real' windshields (car ones, at least) usually use DC brushed motors with gear reductions and cam switches.

Stepper motors are fine but be careful since they lose torque really quick when driven fast. I actually have *no idea* on the mechanical torque needed for the application.

I would use a BDC motor with maybe some form of encoder feedback to do such a thing. While they are somewhat less popular gived the rise of BLDC I think that the brushed DC is still very suitable in many application